# SSRS ReportViewer Not working, only displays a random GUID

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have been using SSRS with a Report Viewer in my asp.net Web Forms application for several years. Within the last few weeks when I run the report through Visual Studio every report just displays a GUID instead of the actual report. I can make changes to all the reports and when I upload to the live server they work fine. I just can no longer run / debug reports from Visual Studio locally. Everything builds and publishes fine. Not sure what else I can do except try to uninstall some VS updates to see if one of those broke it.

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.8.6
- Report Viewer Version 12.0.0.0

Here are some of my web.config settings

```
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.6.1" explicit="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had Enabled JavaScript debugging enabled:

```
 Tools->Options->Debugging->General "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)"
```

Once I shut that off the reports worked fine again. Hopefully that helps someone else.